# Psuedo-random generation: is this more or less random?

Tags: python, random

I'm curious about how this works out mathematically, but I'm not smart enough to figure it out myself. (I tried)

If you generate a list of 1000 psuedo-random numbers, such as:

```
random_numbers = []
for i in range(1,1000):
    random_numbers.append(random.randrange(1000,9999))
```

Then generate another psuedo-random number to use as an index for the list:

```
final_value = random_numbers[rand.randrange(1,1000)]
```

Intuitively, this seems like it would be *more* random than simply generating 1 psuedo-random value like this:

`number = random.randrage(1000,9999)`

However, I know there's often a lot of gotchas with randomness so I figured I'd ask you guys.

Comment: With a high-quality generator this shouldn't make a difference, though it could conceivably help reduce auto-correlations with things like linear congruential generators. Having said that, this doesn't seem like a sufficiently focused question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is easy to mess up random number generation by trying to do it yourself. If a PRNG is good, it is random enough already and there's no need to try to make it better. If a PRNG is not good, use one that is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough, it's the same!

While it seems intuitive that you'd end up with a more random number because you're "adding more randomness" to your pick by running the random number generator repeatedly - because `randrange` [approximates a uniform distribution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) your sample space ends up being identical between the two options. Let's take a look at a simpler example of this:

Say that you've got a standard deck of 52 cards. You pick 10 cards from this list at random while allowing yourself to pick duplicate cards (ie. you could end up picking the same card multiple times). The chance that you'll pick any card in particular is equal to:

10 * 1/52 = 10/52

Because the odds of you picking the card each time is 1/52 and you repeat that 10 times. Now, let's assume that we've picked our card in the first group: how likely is it going to be that we're going to pick it from the second group? Well we'll have a 1 in 10 chance to pick it now!

The probability that we'll pick any particular card in the first pick *and then* the second pick is:

10/52 * 1/10 = 1/52

Which is the exact same probability as picking any old card in the first place!

Comment: This is a good answer for genuinely random number generators (so +1 for the relevant math), but for *pseudo*random number generators the story is more complicated. For a weak generator, OP's scheme could possibly help (and possibly hurt).